# Using an annotation in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to use an annotation in Scala:

```
  //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
  def method123 = someObject.someMethod456
```

If I un-comment it out, it will cause an error of

```
 type mismatch;
[error]  found   : String("unused")
[error]  required: Array[String]
[error]   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

What's up with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead

```
 @SuppressWarnings(Array("unused"))
```

Also, `SuppressWarnings` annotation with [array initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.5) is perfectly legal in *java*:

```
 @SuppressWarnings({"unused"})
```

That's because [`SuppressWarnings#value` is an array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html#value%28%29).

**Edit**

There is some java-specific syntactic sugar.

[jls 9.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1):

> > If the element type is an array type and the corresponding ElementValue is not an ElementValueArrayInitializer, then an array value whose sole element is the value represented by the ElementValue is associated with the element
> >     ...
> >
> > In other words, it is permissible to omit the curly braces when a single-element array is to be associated with an array-valued annotation type element.

But `{ ElementValuesopt ,opt }` is illegal in *scala*, that's the reason why `Array("unused")` should be used in the example above.